# REQUEST_TIMEOUT when instantiating my mart contarct on IBM blockchain Hyperledger Fabric network IBM. VS CODE is used for Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

The output which I get on instantiating is the following one:

```
[8/10/2020 2:39:12 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:09:12.607 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0ae [mychannel][a6cbc10c] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (471ms)
[8/10/2020 2:39:12 am] [INFO] 1org_couchdb0.org1.example.com|[notice] 2020-10-07T21:09:12.599177Z nonode@nohost <0.12842.10> ac663dcc46 couchdb0.org1.example.com:5984 172.19.0.4 undefined GET /mychannel_lscc/_all_docs?attachments=true&include_docs=true&inclusive_end=false&limit=1001&startkey=%22%5Cu0001%22 200 ok 160
[8/10/2020 2:39:12 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:09:12.635 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0af unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=564.2406ms
[8/10/2020 2:52:43 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:43.879 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b0 [][f6d30b56] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc" 
[8/10/2020 2:52:43 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:43.881 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b1 [][f6d30b56] Exit chaincode: name:"cscc"  (2ms)
[8/10/2020 2:52:43 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:43.881 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0b2 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=4.7732ms
[8/10/2020 2:52:43 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:43.924 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b3 [][95f1c8c4] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
[8/10/2020 2:52:43 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:43.928 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b4 [][95f1c8c4] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (3ms)
[8/10/2020 2:52:43 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:43.928 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0b5 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=4.471ms
[8/10/2020 2:52:44 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:44.017 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b6 [mychannel][5992a35f] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
[8/10/2020 2:52:44 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:44.080 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b7 [mychannel][5992a35f] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (63ms)
[8/10/2020 2:52:44 am] [INFO] 1org_couchdb0.org1.example.com|[notice] 2020-10-07T21:22:44.080197Z nonode@nohost <0.26258.10> 036bc4fbca couchdb0.org1.example.com:5984 172.19.0.4 undefined GET /mychannel_lscc/_all_docs?attachments=true&include_docs=true&inclusive_end=false&limit=1001&startkey=%22%5Cu0001%22 200 ok 34
[8/10/2020 2:52:44 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:44.082 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0b8 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=65.313ms
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.155 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b9 [][77e2df0a] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.157 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0ba [][77e2df0a] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (1ms)
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.157 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0bb unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=2.4245ms
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.261 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0bc [mychannel][2b2bd75d] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.267 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0bd [mychannel][2b2bd75d] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (5ms)
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.274 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0be unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=13.803ms
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_couchdb0.org1.example.com|[notice] 2020-10-07T21:22:53.267012Z nonode@nohost <0.26258.10> 5f1944d2e0 couchdb0.org1.example.com:5984 172.19.0.4 undefined GET /mychannel_lscc/_all_docs?attachments=true&include_docs=true&inclusive_end=false&limit=1001&startkey=%22%5Cu0001%22 200 ok 3
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.351 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0bf [mychannel][81c6b21d] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc" 
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.354 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0c0 [mychannel][81c6b21d] Exit chaincode: name:"cscc"  (2ms)
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.355 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0c1 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=4.7228ms
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:22:53.478 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0c2 [mychannel][ed0ce65e] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
[8/10/2020 2:52:53 am] [INFO] 1org_couchdb0.org1.example.com|[notice] 2020-10-07T21:22:53.489098Z nonode@nohost <0.26258.10> 9408c35447 couchdb0.org1.example.com:5984 172.19.0.4 undefined GET /mychannel_lscc/yup?attachments=true 404 ok 2
[8/10/2020 2:53:34 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:23:33.998 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0c3 [][fe545044] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc" 
[8/10/2020 2:53:34 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:23:34.000 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0c4 [][fe545044] Exit chaincode: name:"cscc"  (1ms)
[8/10/2020 2:53:34 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:23:34.000 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0c5 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=3.5826ms
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:28:33.116 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0c6 [mychannel][ed0ce65e] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (339638ms)
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:28:33.159 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 0c7 [mychannel][ed0ce65e] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode yup:0.0.1 for transaction
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:75
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).LaunchInit
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:130
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).ExecuteLegacyInit
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:222
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).ExecuteLegacyInit
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:131
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:183
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:247
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:500
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:169
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:31
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/throttle.go:54
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:91
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:30
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:39
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:171
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:982
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1208
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:686
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|runtime.goexit
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|  /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337
[8/10/2020 2:58:33 am] [INFO] 1org_peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-07 21:28:33.159 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0c8 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:46704 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=5m39.6843113s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing a REQUEST_TIMEOUT error it's worth increasing the client timeout value. This can be changed in the User Settings.

[image]